# Passing Binding to PreviewProvider - Cannot find $BindingABC in scope

Tags: variables, swiftui, binding, tabview

I am trying to control the attributes, color/active, of a TabView from other views. A @State var selectedTab is created and then bound to the other Views that require it. This is a follow on from a previous question that workingdog-support-ukraine helped with no end.

The tab bar menu looks like this:

[image]

The TabView code is as follows (shorted for sanity):

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuView: View {

@State var selectedTab = Tab.location

public enum Tab: Hashable {
        case location
        case calculate
        case install
        case results
        case about
}

struct LocationView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab
    var body: some View {
        Button("click me LocationView", action: {selectedTab = Tab.calculate} )
    }
}
...
 
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            LocationView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Location", systemImage: "globe.europe.africa")
                }
                .tag(Tab.location)
                ...
        } // TabView
        .accentColor(.yellow) 
        .toolbarBackground(Color(UIColor.label), for: .tabBar)
    }                                                                       
}                                                                           

init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red             
    UITabBar.appearance().isOpaque = false
    }
}

struct MenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
     static var previews: some View {
         MenuView()
     }
}
```

The sample view being called, LocationView, is (again shortened):

```
Import SwiftUI

struct LocationView: View {

@Binding var selectedTab: Tab
   
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
    }
}

struct LocationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    LocationView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
    }
}
```

The penultimate line:

```
LocationView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
```

generates a red "Cannot find '$selectedTab' in scope" error. The previews appears to demand the binding but how do I phrase it? Redeclaring it, for example, doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a value to the view in your preview. To pass a binding to a value you can use `.constant`

```
static var previews: some View {
    LocationView(selectedTab: .constant(.location))
}
```

Comment: That gets rid of the scope error but now generates "Type 'Tab' has no member 'location'", which is clearly does. Is the .constant expecting an integer and not a Tab? Have tried various combinations without success.

Comment: .constant is expecting a value of type Tab since selectedTab is defined as Binding<Tab>. It is not clear from your code in what scope Tab is defined, I had it on the top level in my file so the same scope as the view. Try with adding the type name, Tab.location

Comment: I tried several constructs: Tab.location and integer etc. .constant doesn't seem to like the Tab type? I am trying to control the TabBar attributes from different Views. Should I be going about this a different way? The SO advice to date has been get this approach working.

Comment: I can't really help you much more, if LocationView understands what `Tab` is then so should the preview if they are declared in the same scope.

Comment: Indeed - thanks for you help and introducing me to the .constant